# Django MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, media, django-media

I'm trying to upload an image via the Django admin and then view that image either in a page on the frontend or just via a URL.

Note this is all on my local machine.

My settings are as follows:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/dan/mysite/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have set the upload_to parameter to 'images' and the file has been correctly uploaded to the directory:

```
'/home/dan/mysite/media/images/myimage.png'
```

However, when I try to access the image at the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/myimage.png
```

I get a 404 error.

Do I need to setup specific URLconf patters for uploaded media?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

**UPDATE for Django >= 1.7**

Per Django 2.1 documentation: [Serving files uploaded by a user during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

You no longer need `if settings.DEBUG` as Django will handle ensuring this is only used in Debug mode.

---

**ORIGINAL answer for Django <= 1.6**

Try putting this into your *urls.py*

```
from django.conf import settings

# ... your normal urlpatterns here

if settings.DEBUG:
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

With this you can serve the static media from Django when `DEBUG = True` (when you run on local computer) but you can let your web server configuration serve static media when you go to production and `DEBUG = False`

Comment: PS. You can then use this in your templates:
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/myimage.png"/>

Comment: I don't think it's good to add `^` sign before `media//(?P<path>.*)$`, sometime when we access media file in app url path (like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/media/img/logo.png`), this regular won't math.

Comment: I've been struggling for 2 days now why my images return 404. This is the only thing I'm missing and I can't find it in Django doc. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using Django 1.5+, please see the answer below; it is a better solution.

Comment: is this in your app or project urls.py?

Comment: Will this work outside debug mode? If not, do you know how it can be made to work? I plan to run the app locally only.

Comment: Ok, to answer my own question, see the following two answers. [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7639983) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60466558).

Comment: @MicahCarrick what is "document_root" and how does it work I'm getting document_root not defined.

Answer (score 118):

Please read the official Django DOC carefully and you will find the most fit answer.

The best and easist way to solve this is like below.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: It is a new feature added in django 1.5

Comment: is it ok to use it this way in production with apache?

Comment: @andi - No its not okay to use it this way in production. It should be configured via apache on your production.

Comment: In 1.7 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: But it's OK to leave this code here in production with no `if settings.DEV` check because it's disabled automatically?

Comment: Just to follow up @jozxyqk 's comment, I understand that there is no need to use `if settings.DEBUG:` as the answer below, if the code will be used in production?

Comment: For **Django 2.0.***, check out the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

Answer (score 78):

For Django 1.9, you need to add the following code as per the documentation :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

For more info, you can refer here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: This is the solution for django >1.9, thnks.

Comment: Just make sure to put this into the urls.py of your **project** and not of your app, what I accidentally did.

Comment: Worked for me on 1.10 too.

Comment: does not work for me. Perhaps there are any necesary underlying settings in settings.py?

Answer (score 40):

Here What i did in Django 2.0. Set  First MEDIA_ROOT an MEDIA_URL in `setting.py`

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data/') # 'data' is my media folder
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Then Enable the `media` `context_processors`  in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` by adding

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            #here add your context Processors
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Your  `media context processor` is enabled, Now every `RequestContext` will contain a variable `MEDIA_URL`.

Now  you can access  this in your `template_name.html`

```
<p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/image_001.jpeg"/></p>
```

Comment: wonderfully explained -- this was the answer for me. The key was *adding the media context processor*.

Comment: very nice `context_processors` tip

Answer (score 24):

> Do I need to setup specific URLconf patters for uploaded media?

Yes. For development, it's as easy as adding this to your URLconf:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static',
        (r'media/(?P<path>.*)', 'serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```

However, for production, you'll want to serve the media using Apache, lighttpd, nginx, or your preferred web server.

Comment: What does that mean how do you configure the server?

Comment: I get an unresolved reference to "patterns", is that imported from somewhere?

Answer (score 10):

If you'r using python 3.0+ then configure your project as below

Setting

```
STATIC_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'static'
MEDIA_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Main Urls

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlspatterns=[
........
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 6):

(at least) for Django 1.8:

If you use

```
if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns.append(url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

as described above, make sure that no "catch all" url pattern, directing to a default view, comes before that in urlpatterns = []. As .append will put the added scheme to the end of the list, it will of course only be tested if no previous url pattern matches. You can avoid that by using something like this where the "catch all" url pattern is added at the very end, independent from the if statement:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns.append(url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))

urlpatterns.append(url(r'$', 'views.home', name='home')),
```

Answer (score 6):

Here are the changes I had to make to deliver PDFs for the [django-publications](https://github.com/lucastheis/django-publications) app, using Django 1.10.6:

Used the same definitions for media directories as you, in `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/mysite/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

As provided by @thisisashwanipandey, in the project's main `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and a modification of the answer provided by @r-allela, in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # ... the rest of your context_processors goes here ...
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
         },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another problem you are likely to face after setting up all your URLconf patterns is that the variable `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` won't work in your templates. To fix this,in your **settings.py**, make sure you add

> django.core.context_processors.media

in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Comment: This is better option but 'django.template.context_processors.media' worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Following the steps mentioned above for =>3.0 for Debug mode

```
urlpatterns = [
...
]
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And also the part that caught me out, ***the above static URL only worked in my main project urls.py file.*** I was first attempting to add to my app, and wondering why I couldn't see the images.

Lastly make sure you set the following:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 3):

This if for Django 1.10:

```
 if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to  Micah Carrick answer for django 1.8:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns.append(url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Comment: Does not work for me (1.10). `TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to achieve image rendering in DEBUG = False mode in Python 3.6 with Django 1.11

```
from django.views.static import serve
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
# other paths
]
```

Answer (score 2):

On production environment Django does not load the media root automatically so that we can overcome that issue by adding following codes right after URL patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
       ''''
         your urls
       ''''
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                              document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If you are using more than one app and if you are including app urls on main app url, just add this code(configuration) on main project URL.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code below to **"settings.py"** to access(open or display)uploaded files:

```py
# "urls.py"

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Django 3.0+ in development have the below in your main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   # rest of your url paths here..
]

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += (
        static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) +
        static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in `settings.py`

```
urlpatterns = [ 

....

....


]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```