# Serving static files for development mode in Django

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

I'm having trouble serving static files in development mode in Django. I do know that this is not a setting that should be used in a production server, so don't worry. For now however I'd like to stick to it.

The relevant parts of `settings.py` are:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/..'), 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/..'), 'static')
```

And of `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

So the static files are located for now in the directory named `static` right outside the project folder. I verified that `STATIC_ROOT` is evaluated to an appropriate value. I've double checked that the folder exists.

However when pointing my browser to the address `localhost:8000/static/js/somefile.js`, I get the dreaded `404 Page Not Found` with the message `'js/somefile.js' could not be found.`. Could you please suggest some reasons to this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I think I know where the problem may be: The thing is that in development mode Django attempts to look for the files from the `STATIC_URL` in the `static/` subdirectories of all the installed apps. However I've added some additional files to my `STATIC_ROOT` and these are not served at all. Maybe there is some clash.

**EDIT (2):**

This must be it. When I run the server with `./manage.py runserver --nostatic` it works, that is it actually serves the files from the `STATIC_ROOT` directory. What can I do about it? The problem is that just as I try to keep all my template files separate from the project itself I try to do the same with certain css and js files...

Comment: In your first edit you say that "in development mode Django attempts to look for the files from the STATIC_URL in the static/ subdirectories of all the installed apps" but this is not exactly true, what happens is you run manage.py collectstatic and it copies the files from the installed apps into STATIC_ROOT. If you are able to get files served when you use --nostatic option then you must be using apache or something to serve on your STATIC_URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because what I was trying to do wasn't very wise.

That's how it should be configured. `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'media.mydomain.com'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static.mydomain.com'

STATIC_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/..'), 'static'),
)
```

All the files remain in place, exactly where they were.

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT are wrong here... they should be file paths (on disk) not domain names.

Comment: Then, did you mean `STATICFILES_DIRS` instead of `STATIC_DIRS`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, adding an explicit reference to the media location in my urlconf as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root) fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I'll try it in a sec. The problem is that this is I think the exact contents of the `static()` function.

Comment: Maybe an issue with what you have your ADMIN_ROOT set to? I think it has to be set to something different from MEDIA_ROOT. Maybe a file system permissions issue? Sorry not an expert I just had a similar problem and spent some time trying to work it out.