# Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?

Tags: django, django-views, django-staticfiles

Am building an app using Django as my workhorse. All has been well so far - specified db settings, configured static directories, urls, views etc. But trouble started sneaking in the moment I wanted to render my own beautiful and custom 404.html and 500.html pages.

I read the docs on custom error handling, and set necessary configurations in UrlsConf, created corresponding views and added the 404.html and the 500.html to my app's template directory (specified in the settings.py too).

But the docs say `you can actually view custom error views until Debug is Off`, so I did turn it off to test my stuff, and that's when stuff goes berserk!

Not only do I fail to view the custom 404.html (actually, it loads, but because my error pages each contain a graphic error message -as some nice image), the source of the error page loads, but nothing else loads! Not even linked CSS or Javascript!

Generally, once I set `DEBUG = False`, all views will load, but any linked content (CSS, Javascript, Images, etc) wont load! What's happening? Is there something am missing, concerning static files and the `DEBUG` setting?

Comment: How are you hosting? Local machine with the test server?

Comment: local machine with test server. I basically want to see how my custom error handling would work by locally simulating scenarios such as accessing non-existing pages and causing run-time errors - but my static content wont load.

Comment: Either it can be done at server level like here or it can be handled at Django level by adding urlpattern. I found this below question for the same problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405173/static-files-wont-load-when-out-of-debug-in-django

Answer (score 486, accepted):

With debug turned off Django won't handle static files for you any more - your production web server (Apache or something) should take care of that.

Comment: This actually settles my curiosity, so now it makes sense, and i can indeed take care of it with Apache if need be then. I'd thought it was a problem with my own settings. Thanks

Comment: I found this answer very helpful. Just in case someone else is in my same situation (using Google App Engine for the app with nonrel django): don't forget to update app.yaml.

Comment: handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. I would like to test it locally somehow with Debug=False

Comment: @PhilippS. It doesn't matter you can also test it with Debug=False and an local Apache server (not using `./manage.py runserver` but a locally run Apache server).

Comment: This package solved the issue for me: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Comment: `manage.py runserver --insecure` works for serving static files with debug=True

Answer (score 615):

If you still need to server static locally (e.g. for testing without debug) you can run devserver in insecure mode:

```
manage.py runserver --insecure
```

Comment: @astrocybernaute make sure you have staticfiles app installed

Comment: Whilst this flag does work, it does not serve the content from the collectstatic folder

Comment: That's magic. Thank you sir, you're a hero. This answer should be merged with the accepted answer as it solves the problem without having to serve static using another way than django itself.

Comment: This was all I needed. Although the best practice would be to use environment variable to differentiate between development and production environment and Debug toggle.

Comment: Please note: that's will NOT work with ManifestStaticFilesStorage as https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19295

Comment: can someone tell me though what is so insecure about this

Comment: @KaviVaidya - It's only insecure because it hasn't been carefully checked to have confidence that it is secure. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31097709/303056 for details. IMHO this is a really poor choice of naming, conflating FUD about security with clear performance limitations.

Comment: It throws this error: `manage.py runserver: error: unrecognized arguments: --insecure
`

Comment: It seems it's not an option any more on Django 3.1. There is no `--insecure` in help and adding it does nothing. Seems we now need `gunicorn`, `nginx` and so on for prod

Comment: @Leopd It's not FUD - it's really less secure. There is no focus on security for this server. Not saying it's designed insecurely, but it doesn't receive the same rigorous security testing that webservers have. And when it's breached you're very likely to land in a directory with write privileges and access to the application code. A well-configured image server doesn't suffer from these extra weaknesses.

Comment: Well,it's still in django 3.2 and django3.1's official guide. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-runserver-insecure

Comment: If 'daphne' is installed apps, you won't be able to use --insecure flag since Daphne overrides runserver command thus removing the ability to serve static files. If you are just debugging to see how templates will look like, you may remove Daphne temporarily.

Answer (score 112):

First you need to add STATIC_ROOT in your settings.py.

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

Make sure BASE_DIR is already defined.

Then you'll need to add following code in you app's root urls.py.

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    # your other paths here
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
```

Then you'll need to run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Lastly run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and now you should be able to load your static files.

Comment: AWESOME! Don't forget to set STATIC_ROOT and manage.py collectstatic.

Comment: Nowadays replace `url(` with `re_path(`

Comment: This actually works while the app is in local but it wont work after it gets deployed

Comment: its really cool.. I am using this for my project which only installed in local machine... thanks a ton!

Comment: where to import settings from ?

Answer (score 57):

You can use [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) to serve static files in production.

Install:

```
pip install WhiteNoise==2.0.6
```

And change your **wsgi.py** file to this:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

And you're good to go!

Credit to [Handlebar Creative Blog](http://handlebarcreative.tumblr.com/post/104881545637/deploying-django-applications-in-docker).

BUT, it's really not recommended serving static files this way in production. Your production web server(like nginx) should take care of that.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but didn't work for me by just adding that line to the `wgsi.py` file. The documentation you linked seems to give other instructions for using WhiteNoise. Will try other ways and update you here.

Comment: +1 as this was what eventually led me to the solution. I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49889262/3908170) where I included the additional steps I took to actually make it work.

Comment: `manage.py runserver --insecure` didn't work for me. This one does, though.

Comment: Note that with WhiteNoise release 4.0, the configuration changed. Do not add these lines to wsgi.py. Instead, just add `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'` to middleware. See [release notes](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0) from the changelog

Comment: Why is *not recommended? I've been using it for years in several sites, works great. Even Heroku uses it in their Django template.

Comment: how about asgi? Thanks!

Comment: @OmarGonzalez for your question, please refer Marek answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5836728/3992524 this answer is old(2016) and next sentence has explain why not recommanded

Answer (score 24):

Johnny's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35408791/3908170) is great, but still didn't work for me just by adding those lines described there. Based on that answer, the steps that actually worked for me where:

1. Install [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) as described:

   ```
   pip install WhiteNoise
   ```
2. Create the `STATIC_ROOT` variable and add WhiteNoise to your `MIDDLEWARE` variable in `settings.py`:

   ```py
   #settings.py
   MIDDLEWARE = [
       'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
       'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', #add whitenoise
       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
       ...
   ]

   #...

   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') ##specify static root
   ```
3. Then, modify your `wsgi.py` file as explained in Johnny's answer:

   ```py
   #wsgi.py
   from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
   from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

   application = get_wsgi_application()
   application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
   ```
4. After that, deploy your changes to your server (with git or whatever you use).
5. Finally, run the [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#deployment) option from your `manage.py` on your server. This will copy all files from your static folders into the `STATIC_ROOT` directory we specified before:

   ```
   $ python manage.py collectstatic
   ```

   You will now see a new folder named `staticfiles` that contains such elements.

After following these steps you can now run your server and will be able to see your static files while in Production mode.

*Update:* In case you had version < 4 the [changelog](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0) indicates that it's no longer necessary to declare the `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'projectName.wsgi.application'` on your `settings.py` file.

Comment: I did it accordingly, and on development it served fine, but not in production. Still have the same issue when DEBUG == False

Comment: @AnnaHuang What do you mean by in development and in production? Do you have separate environments or machines? Are they configured the same way?

Comment: @DarkCygnus did you mean "version > 4"?

Comment: @AnnaHuang did you checkout the Update at the bottom of this post? After I deleted the "WSGI_APPLICATION" setting it started working in production.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using the static serve view in development, you have to have DEBUG = True :

> Warning
>
> This will only work if DEBUG is True.
>
> That's because this view is grossly
> inefficient and probably insecure.
> This is only intended for local
> development, and should never be used
> in production.

[Docs: serving static files in developent](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)

- Updated [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view), and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

EDIT: You could add some urls just to test your 404 and 500 templates, just use the generic view direct_to_template in your urls.

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^404testing/$', direct_to_template, {'template': '404.html'})
)
```

Comment: you would set up your web server to host a specific directory. Most commonly you'd be using Apache or Nginx. [The Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production) go into it a bit.

Comment: thanks @j_syk, I’d already tried this approach of viewing the 404.html and 500.html  via some other non-error mechanism similar to what u suggest. But i wanted to know whether it was totally impossible to have my pages render correctly as they would in production, while still merely running on my testing server - the delegation of static file handling to Apache when Debug is Off settles it for me. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: @mcnemesis I'm not sure exactly what will happen- but try setting TEMPLATE_DEBUG=False, and DEBUG=True. If you turn off the pretty errors I'm not sure if it goes to the 404/500 templates instead

Comment: like expected, doing this didn't yield any positive results.But thanks still.

Answer (score 16):

You actually can serve static files in a production Django app, securely and without `DEBUG=True`.

Rather than using Django itself, use [dj_static](http://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/introducing-dj-static) in your WSGI file ([github](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-static)):

requirements.txt:

```
...
dj-static==0.0.6
```

YOURAPP/settings.py:

```
...
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticdir'
STATIC_URL = '/staticpath/'
```

YOURAPP/wsgi.py:

```
...
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Comment: I've since discovered [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/), which may be more full-featured.

Answer (score 11):

From here I took help by mixing a few answers. Here, I am adding my whole parts. **[I am doing this for a beginners help and for my future use as well]**

Well at first the question is why `Debug=False` needed!
I put my project in AWS and it was being connection timeout after few hours because of memory leaking.
At first I thought for celery. [of course I am just a beginner]
Then I put `DEBUG=False` from `DEBUG=True` As we can see the security warning in settings.py

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
```

Once I did that my staticfiles were not loading successfully in webpages.
Then I searched everywhere and at first tried from here the --insecure command to runserver.

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```

Which is successful but I don't want the insecure mode in my project when it is in production.
And as the proper solution [according to me] I followed the steps below.

At first, I correct the static URL,root, and dir in **settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Then collect the static files by command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Now the second step, [which also provided here]
At first install whitenoise in your project directory in the command line

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Then Add 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware' in your middleware list in settings.py.

This should be added just below the 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware' and above all the remaining middleware. So that your middleware list will look like this:-

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', #after this line
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', #add it exactlyhere
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', #before this
    '...'
]
```

Add 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic' on top of your installed apps So that your installed apps list will look like this:-

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    '...'
]
```

Done, you will be able to serve static files in production now!! [I did on my local environment as well]

Just use the runserver command as always no insecure or anything needed.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

**Boom!!! It's working for me.**
Hahaha. I know kinda childish nature but I am so happy now.

Thanks to everyone who provided answers here and help my work.

Answer (score 9):

Ultimate solution:-

So basically when you make debug = False, Django doesn't want to take care of your static files.

So we want something that can take care of our files.

The answer is whitenoise.

1. **pip install whitenoise** in your environment
2. Add **'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'** in your middleware list in settings.py.

   This should be added just below the **'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'** and above all the remaining middleware. So that your middleware list will look like this:-

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
       'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
       'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
       # add it exactlyhere
       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
       '...'
   ]
   ```
3. Add **'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic'** on top of your installed apps
   So that your installed apps list will look like this:-

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       '...'
   ]
   ```

Done, you will be able to serve static files in production now!!

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked for me. But if someone just following this then plz at first collect the static files.

Answer (score 7):

You can debug this in many different ways. Here's my approach.

localsettings.py:

```
DEBUG = False
DEBUG404 = True
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
import os

if settings.DEBUG404:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')} ),
    )
```

Be sure to read the docs ;)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#limiting-use-to-debug-true

Comment: Thanks it worked for me by only adding the: DEBUG = False
DEBUG404 = True

Answer (score 6):

For last versions of Django please look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7639983/6180987

**For django version below 1.10** the solution should work:

Just open your project urls.py, then find this if statement.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)','serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

You can change settings.DEBUG on True and it will work always. But if your project is a something serious then you should to think about other solutions mentioned above.

```
if True:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)','serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

In django 1.10 you can write so:

```
urlpatterns += [ url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, { 'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, }), url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, { 'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT }), ]
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but in Django 1.10, the configuration is for media and static is: urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),

    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
     'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT
    }),
]

Answer (score 6):

This is Exactly you must type on terminal to run your project without DEBUG = TRUE
and then you see all assets (static) file is loading correctly On local server .

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```

`--insecure` : it means you can run server without security mode

Comment: easiest answer. adding middleware just to debug 404 styles in development is an overkill. funny thing is i went looking for this flag but could find no mention of it on [django's manage.py documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Marek Sapkota answer; But you can still use django **URFConf** to reallocate the url, if static file is requested.

Step 1: Define a `STATIC_ROOT` path in settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Step 2: Then collect the static files

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

Step 3: Now define your URLConf that if static is in the beginning of url, access files from the static folder `staticfiles`. NOTE: This is your project's urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve

urlpattern += [
  re_path(r'^static/(?:.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, })
]
```

Answer (score 4):

when i make `DEBUG = True` my static are doesn't work.

if i run my project in `python manage.py runserver --insecure` . By this i got my static as well.

Solution 1:

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```

Solution 2:

But I Need Permanent Solution. then i install `pip install dj-static==0.0.6` and add some code to my wsgi.py file:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

and then i added some in setting.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## nginx,settings and url configs

If you're on linux this may help.

#### nginx file

your_machn:/#vim etc/nginx/sites-available/nginxfile

```
server {
    server_name xyz.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/your_prj;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/your_prj;
    }
...........
......
}
```

### urls.py

```
.........
   .....
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('test/', test_viewset.TestServer_View.as_view()),
        path('api/private/', include(router_admin.urls)),
        path('api/public/', include(router_public.urls)),    
        ]
    
    if settings.DEBUG:
        import debug_toolbar
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
        urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

### settings.py

```
.....
........
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
.....
....
```

**Ensure to run:**

```
(venv)yourPrj$ ./manage.py collectstatic
yourSys# systemctrl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 2):

## This is normal and intended behavior.

```
Warning

This will only work if DEBUG is True.  
you can actually view custom error views until Debug is Off
```

If Django is just reading from the filesystem and sending out a file, then it has no advantage over a normal web server, all web servers are capable to server the files on it's own.

Furthermore, if you serve static files with Django, you will keep the Python process busy for the duration of the request and it will be unable to serve the dynamic requests to which it is more suited.

For these reasons, the **Django static view is designed only for use during development and will not work if your DEBUG setting is False.**

Since during development we only usually have one person accessing the site at a time (the
developer), Django is fine to serve static files.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem today and this fixed it while on development, If you still need to server static locally (e.g. for testing without debug) you can run devserver in insecure mode:

`manage.py runserver --insecure`

Don't worry because when in production, this hosting platform (Apache,  Heroku  E.T.C ) would handle serving the static files for you.

Note: Heroku Doesn't server static files, you'd want to put it on AWS or MS Azure

Answer (score 1):

Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10

My solution is just small correction to Conrado solution above.

```
from django.conf import settings
import os
from django.views.static import serve as staticserve

if settings.DEBUG404:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', staticserve,
            {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')} ),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following changes to my project/urls.py and it worked for me

Add this line  :
from django.conf.urls import url

and add :
`url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, })`,
in urlpatterns.

Answer (score 1):

In production mode, the static files are no longer served by Django, but rather they should be served by Apache or NGINX, and hence you will need to configure them.

On the other hand, in case you wanted to let Django serve them, then the code below helps to let the static files be served by Django when `DEBUG=False`.

You can try it by appending the code below to the main `urls.py` file:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve


urlpatterns += (
re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

Then, do "collectstatic":

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Credit to [@stathoula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722734/11554367). Following her answer along with the remark of [@leopd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303056/leopd) (adding `re_path` to her answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not safest, but you can change in the source code. navigate to `Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/static.py`

Then edit like following:

```
if settings.DEBUG or (prefix and '://' in prefix):
```

So then if `settings.debug==False` it won't effect on the code, also after running try `python manage.py runserver --runserver` to run static files.

**NOTE**: Information should only be used for testing only