# heroku-django-uploaded image is not displayed if DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django, heroku

I deployed my Django app on heroku. Every thing is working fine except displaying images. Any uploaded image is not displayed if DEBUG=False.

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['salma-blog.herokuapp.com']

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.dirname(myblog.__file__)+'/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#upload images
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.dirname(myblog.__file__)+'/static/myblog/images'
MEDIA_URL='/images/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
   ...
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

image tag in my template

```
<img alt="img" src="/blog{{image}}"></a>
```

Comment: Is the image being displayed with DEBUG=FALSE on your local **python django server** ??

Comment: no, on heroku server

Comment: So you mean to say that the image is being displayed in case of your local python django server with DEBUG=FALSE but not getting displayed on Heroku Server with DEBUG=FALSE? Or is it not being displayed anywhere, be it heroku or local python Django server??

Comment: the image is not being displayed if DEBUG=FALSE whether I am using my local python server or Heroku server

Comment: Just a quick reminder, if your repository weights more than 300 MB (or so) your pictures will be automatically deleted. It's all in their docs. If you have an app that will store a lot of images consider using AWS S3 in your django.

Comment: Thank you. When DEBUG=True. images are displayed correctly, so I think the problem is not about the Heroku file system.

Comment: Exactly. Its not related to Heroku. See this -> `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail` and this->`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405173/static-files-wont-load-when-out-of-debug-in-django`

Answer (score 0):

Whitenoise uses [static file finders](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#WHITENOISE_USE_FINDERS) when `DEBUG=True`, so you most likely have a problem with your static file collection process.

Update your `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` settings to a recommended method, such as:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')
```