# Django cant find static files on server, but works fine on local machine

Tags: django, git, python-3.x, nginx, webserver

I have a vps running with django, i'm developing the site from my local machine, and pushing it up to the vps by git.

On my local machine i've just installed the initializr, and changed all scripts to use the static location, and everything works fine there, but when i push it to my vps, all it finds is the .html files, it cant find either .css or .js scripts
the vps is running Debian 8.* Minimal, with nginx, and gunicorn
My local machine is running MacOs
Both machines runs Python 3.6.2, and Django 1.11.4

Here are the relevant settings from settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "BaseFiles/templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "BaseFiles/static"),
)
```

My paths are:

```
Project_folder/ -> BaseFiles  |  Django_project | manage.py
BaseFiles/ -> static  |  templates
```

***UPDATE***
Okay so it turns out, that if i run django manually from the vps, it loads the css and js files fine, so the problem is isolated to Nginx

Nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domaine.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/project_folder;
    }
```

So it turns out i had a misconfiguration in my nginx site file.
After adding the below after project_folder it worked fine

```
/BaseFiles
```

Comment: please, add error trace you have.

Comment: There is no error trace i just get an html page with no css or javascript, consol just says it cant find the files at domain.com/static/*

Comment: on server django in mode `DEBUG=False`, on local machine `DEBUG=True`? if so the answer can help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6406429/8060120

Comment: Both set to True :) as i said i just get the html page where the console tells the static arent reachable, the pages dossent crash

Comment: if you run django from console, on vps does all work fine?

Comment: yes, it loads the scripts and everything looks fine if i run it manually from console....
Did i misconfigure Gunicorn?

Comment: i think you need show nginx config and gunicorn config will be useful, and may be someone help you

Comment: Thanks Bear Brown, the problem was with nginx, if you want credit for solving this submit and answer, and i'll accept it :)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad to help you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Give a static root to in your settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/project/static/'
```

And in your nginx:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/project/static/;
}
```

Do `python3 manage.py collectstatic` and `sudo service nginx restart` 
and this should probably work.
Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx is not finding your static files.

You need to collectstatic files and set up the location of the static folder on your setting.py.

Another way is to install whitenoise ( pip install whitenoise ). This plugin do the trick -> https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/whitenoise/