# nginx: check if configured

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

Iam new to nginx and gunicorn.

I have installed and configured nginx.
How to point it to gunicorn?
How to check if nginx and gunicorn are properly configured and working?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my answer to a similar question here about how to configure `nginx.conf` : [Django Gunicorn not load static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175243/django-gunicorn-not-load-static-files/20244325#20244325)
It basically gets what Gunicorn is serving: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;`

Regarding Gunicorn, just start it using: `sudo unicorn name_of_your_app.wsgi:application`. If you don't get any error message, then you are ok. If it gives you an error message and Gunicorn stops, then you have a problem.

Remember to start nginx! If it is already running and you change nginx.conf you have to restart it using: `sudo nginx -s reload`

Good luck!