# staticfiles loaded the wrong path - app_name/static/

Tags: django

it's my very beginning with the django. I've configured server with nginx and gunicorn. The problem is that static files are not being loaded correctly. 
When I go to the source code I can see, f.e:

```
<link href="/app_name/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

although the correct file is located under: /static/css/bootstrap.min.css

So it seems that "app_name" is added before path to my /static/ folder.

settings.py file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/webapps/filmyposlowie/static/'
STATIC_URL =  '/static/'
```

index.html file:

```
   {% load staticfiles %}

    <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

nginx:

```
location /static/ {
    alias   /webapps/filmyposlowie/static/;
}
```

Comment: See this will help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175243/django-gunicorn-not-load-static-files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175243/django-gunicorn-not-load-static-files

Comment: I think that my ngix is properly configured. It's rather a problem in django configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the server after changing setting.py file has helped me. In my case it was: `supervisorctl restart [process_name]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a STATICFILES_STORAGE setting in settings.py?

If not, try changing `{% load staticfiles %}` to `{% load static %}` in your index.html file. I had a similar problem once.

Comment: it doesn't help in this case

Comment: {% load static %} is up to version 1.3

Comment: {% load static %} is still in 1.6 and serves a different purpose than {% load staticfiles %}. See [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#static) Basically, load static works for the STATIC_URL while load staticfiles works with the staticfiles contrib app.