# Not finding static files django 1.9 gunicorn

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-staticfiles

I am on my way to deployment but when I switched to gunicorn from dev server my static files aren't being found.  I ran collectstatic, and the files have been collected.

note in my settings file I print the path to my static files.  This is from my gunicorn log:

```
/home/jcg/code/python/venvs/baseball/baseball_stats/collect_static
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/dashboard.css
```

Here is my settings file.  I have updated correctly (I hope) settings from the original django 1.6 version.

```
"""
Django settings for baseball_stats project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

# this for reading environment variables for private values (secret_key, etc)
# copy this to .bashrc or if using virtualvenvwrapper to bin/postactivate script
# EXPORT VARIABLE=thevaluegoeshere
import get_env_variable

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Most recent year for statistics
MOST_RECENT = 2013

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-s*2+cq_niwa&*b%9(0w6$w!*9%d98oe7r6=+m0v+8(^&!10b6'
SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable.get_env_variable('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'baseball',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'bootstrap3',
    # 'debug_toolbar',
    'django_extensions',
    # 'csvimport',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'baseball_stats.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'baseball_stats.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "collect_static")
print STATIC_ROOT

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
"""
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    }
}
"""
```

I looked at this: [Django Gunicorn not load static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175243/django-gunicorn-not-load-static-files)

But my understanding is gunicorn can do static files, it just isn't as efficient as using nginx.  I thought I would do this as a first step before setting up nginx

Running ./manage.py findstatic doesn't find my files, so, I am guessing its my settings file, not the server

Comment: gunicorn might well be able to do static files, but have you told it to? How? Where?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Third party app

All You need is [dj-static](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dj-static) package.

```
pip install dj-static
```

Configure your static assets in **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then, update your **wsgi.py** file to use dj-static:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

## Pure Django

Add to Your **urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: why do I need a third party app? running findstatic doesn't find my files, so I think its a settings issue

Comment: You dev server works fine? It's not settings problem.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up having to add to urlpatterns.  I ended up spinning up nginx and all worked out well.  I want to accept your answer since it was useful, even though I went in a different direction

Comment: As much as this sounds good, I hate it when third parties are required to serve static files. Django has never wanted to make serving static files any easier. Every release, serving static files gets a new trick up its sleeves. For God's sake, is it a punishment or what? The only problem I've always had with Django, since 1.4 is **always**, serving static files.

Comment: @Rexford Absolutly agree on your point! - Excepting some migration problems in DBs - serving static files was always pain.

Answer (score 4):

you can server the static file from nginx server. In the server setting.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-settings

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name test.com;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
       proxy_redirect off; 
   }
   location /static/ {
       autoindex on;
       alias /home/ec2-user/app/static/;
   }
}
```