# More trailing slashes being added at every refresh - Django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-settings

I'm using django 1.3.1 and in my application and I have set `DEBUG = False` in my settings.py. when I refresh the page, the url is going into some loop process and in every loop a slash is being appended to the static files and due to this no static files are being called. I have pasted a sample terminal output below. What could be reason and how can I resolve this?

```
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:30] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg//////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:30] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg///////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:30] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg////////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:30] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg/////////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:30] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg//////////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:30] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg///////////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:30] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg////////////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:30] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg/////////////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:30] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg//////////////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:31] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg///////////////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:31] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg////////////////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Mar/2013 11:57:31] "GET /static/img/admin/logo.jpg/////////////////// HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

This works fine when I set `DEBUG = True` in my settings.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little search, I found this question very helpful. [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5836674/1095090)

> With debug turned off Django won't handle static files for you any more - your production web server (Apache or something) should take care of that.
>
> If you still need to server static locally (e.g. for testing without debug) you can run devserver in insecure mode: manage.py runserver --insecure