# django endless pagination not working in production but works in development

Tags: django, django-endless-pagination

i am using django-endless-pagination with twitter style for my website and it works perfectly fine in development but when i move to production it is not even showing the entries. I am using webfaction and below is the list of actions i have taken.

1) PYTHONPATH=$HOME/webapps/csiop/lib/python2.7 easy_install-2.7 --install-dir=$HOME/webapps/csiop/lib/python2.7 --script-dir=$HOME/webapps/csiop/bin django-endless-pagination
2) python manage.py syncdb
3) Add endless_pagination to settings.py and below also in settings.py

```
 PAGINATION_SETTINGS = {
  'PAGE_RANGE_DISPLAYED': 10,
  'MARGIN_PAGES_DISPLAYED': 2,
 }
```

4) My views.py is changed to look like below

```
   def homepage(request):
       item_list = items.objects.filter(show_on_website=True)
       template = 'homepage.html'
       page_template = 'home_page_index.html'

       if request.is_ajax():
             template = page_template

       return render_to_response(template,
         {'page_template': page_template,
         'item_list': item_list},
       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

5) And my templates are slipt as below.

Homepage.html:-

```
    <h2>Entries:</h2>
    {% include page_template %}

    {% block js %}
       {{ block.super }}
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
       <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>
       <script>$.endlessPaginate();</script>
    {% endblock %}
```

home_page_index.html:-

```
   {% load endless %}

   {% lazy_paginate entries %}
      {% for entry in entries %}
        {# your code to show the entry #}
      {% endfor %}
   {% show_more " " %}
```

the above code works perfectly fine in my development but not in production.
Could someone help what i am missing ?

Edit : - if i set the debug mode to False in my development environment i am getting the below error. I am using django-seo as well in website, it seems to be complaining about that but i am not really sure what the error exactly realtes to.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File            "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
  self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
  response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
  response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 224, in handle_uncaught_exception
  return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
  response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 41, in server_error
   return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render(Context({})))
   File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
   return self._render(context)
   File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
   return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
   bit = self.render_node(node, context)
   File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
   return node.render(context)
   File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 124, in render
   return compiled_parent._render(context)
   File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
   return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
   bit = self.render_node(node, context)
   File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
   return node.render(context)
   File "/Users/django1.5/django1.5_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rollyourown/seo/templatetags/seo.py", line 25, in render
   raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(msg)
   TemplateSyntaxError: {% get_metadata %} needs some path information.
    Please use RequestContext with the django.core.context_processors.request context  processor.
    Or provide a path or object explicitly, eg {% get_metadata for path %} or {%        get_metadata for object %}
   [09/Apr/2013 18:22:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you have debug mode off on your local machine?

Comment: Hi, it is not working in development also if i use debug mode as false. I have updated my question with the error in an edit. it is complaining about metadata in seo, i am not really sure what the issue is. Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-installed django-endless-pagination using pip rather than easy-install and it works fine now.  Looks like the issue is because i installed with easy-install before without -Z before.

Answer (score 1):

When you turn off debug mode, Django stops handling your static files for you. On your remote host, you'll want to set your STATIC_ROOT path in settings and [manage.py collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/). You can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail).

Comment: Hi, i have run the collectstatic as well in my production environment and still it is not working. Even in my local environment, it just gives the error message i have copied in my edit. I tried running the with " manage.py runserver --insecure " as well in my development but still i get the same error.

Comment: Are you using render or render_to_response? There's a bug on the django-seo page about a similar problem but it is from 2 years ago. Is your package up to date? https://github.com/willhardy/django-seo/issues/14

Comment: Yes. my django-seo is upto date and i am using render_to_response. The error starting showing only after i added endless_pagination. If i remove the endless_pagination, then the website works fine without any errors.

Comment: Hmmm... You've already added endless pagination to your context processors? And added it to installed apps as per https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/start.html#settings? I would recommend trying to switch the context processor order for endless pagination. Also make sure "django.core.context_processors.request" is listed in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

Comment: i have tried changing the order as well, even that does not seem to make any difference. If i just use without endless pagination ,then it all works fine. Only if i add endless pagination in production, it is not listing any of list contents.