# How to test custom 404 and 500 pages on development server with static files?

Tags: django

Aside from setting up a webserver and doing collectstatic, is there any way I can see the exact look of my 404 and 500 pages in the development environment with the currect static files, before it gets deployed to production?

See I built custom 404 and 500 pages as per:
[Customised Error Views Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views)

And I try it out on my development server which is using the static pages collecter thingy:
[Staticfiles documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles.django.contrib.staticfiles.urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns)

But the former requires DEBUG be OFF and the latter requires DEBUG be ON!?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seek and I shall find... Apologies. Nothing to see here. The answer is, of course, here...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7639983/75033

```
manage.py runserver --insecure
```