# Django can't find staticfiles with Debug=False and Allowed_Hosts

Tags: django, django-settings, django-staticfiles

Hi all I'm having trouble solving this issue: If I turn DEBUG to False, I can't run manage.py runserver:

```
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False
```

Then, let's say I add something to ALLOWED_HOSTS:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
or
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
or
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

Now, I can do ´manage.py runserver´ but the staticfiles don't work. Weird.

If I turn DEBUG to True, then it works with ALLOWED_HOSTS set to nothing, to localhost or to *. So, I guess the problem has to do with DEBUG. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `DEBUG` mode, the Django development server handles serving static files for you. However, this is not best for production as it's much more inefficient than a true server. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/).

> Serving the files
>
> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files.
>
> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
>
> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.
>
> See Deploying static files for proper strategies to serve static files in production environments.

Check out [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/deployment/) to learn out how to serve static files in production.

EDIT: Adding the following to answer @alejoss question about viewing error pages with DEBUG=True.

I added something like the following to my root `urls.py` file:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^400/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='400.html')),
        url(r'^403/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='403.html')),
        url(r'^404/$', 'django.views.defaults.page_not_found'),
        url(r'^500/$', 'django.views.defaults.server_error'),
    )
```

You might need to alter a bit (i.e., the `400` and `403` pages may need to be edited if your template names are different). Basically, this lets you visit `http://localhost/400` to see your `400` error page, `http://localhost/403` to see your `403` error page, and so on.

Comment: Ok, just ran across the same problem. How am supposed to test my 404.html / 500.html? If debug is false then I get the error, If debug is true then I wont see my error pages. :(

Comment: Hey @alejoss, I edited my original response so you could see it with formatting. Let me know if you have any trouble with it.

Comment: I ran into this issue and just installed [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) to serve the files. While it's serving from the same server, it seems like a good solution for simple applications as all you have to do is add a single line to the `MIDDELWARE` setting.

Answer (score 9):

If you still need to server static locally (e.g. for testing without debug) you can run devserver in insecure mode:

```
manage.py runserver --insecure
```

Comment: The original answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail

Answer (score 1):

Okay Here's the very clean solution. you need to use

```
DEBUG = False
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

This way in your logs you can see what is then problem. Whitenoise returns 500 usually when It is missing some file.

You can see what is missing in you logs. In my case heroku logs were enough.

for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#debug-propagate-exceptions