# Debug set on False and not load styles and pictures

Tags: python, django, image, stylesheet, django-staticfiles

I have a problem with static css files.
I added to your application (in django 1.8) Page 404 - 404 page template and code in a file urls.py:

```
handler404 = 'django.views.defaults.page_not_found'
```

My STATIC_ROOT:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public_assets')
```

In settings.py file, I have the code:

```
Debug = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1',] - also doesn't work
```

After starting website, do not load styles and pictures.

Comment: Do you have a `STATIC_ROOT` set?

Comment: yes, I have: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public_assets')`

Comment: And you have run `collectstatic`? You should post your staticfiles settings above

Comment: Yes, I run collectstatic, but nothing happend

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django can't find staticfiles with Debug=False and Allowed\_Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443991/django-cant-find-staticfiles-with-debug-false-and-allowed-hosts)

Comment: is this run on a production server? or locally? if it is local then the comment below will solve your problems. If it is deployed then you need to set a rule so that the web server (apache or nginx) know where to pull your files from. (alias to their location should work just fine)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work are not

```
if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
                 (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True}),
            )
```

add above at the end of root urls.py
and run collectstatic

Comment: Do not do that. Ever. It is both dangerous and very inefficient. Even the documentation of that view says so. You should be using a webserver in front of Django to (among other things) handle static files.