# Errors occuring after changing mt setting to DEBUG = False

Tags: python, django

I have installed the grapelli admin theme, I also use various javascript files for my templates.

Everything was running fine and after I finished all the various tests, I decided to try setting `DEBUG = False` on my **settings** file.

Immediately after I had 404 issues with grapelli's various files as well as some of my own files.

Why did this happen, I have started suspecting that I must add all of grapelli (installed with pip, and located on Python27) inside my app's templates.

What is the procedure of getting ready for production on a Django app that uses various external modules?

**EDIT**

Since these has to do with my static files then most probably I should have included my setting for static files

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    STATIC_URL = "/static/"

    STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
    )

    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
    )
```

Comment: Check your urls.py. Have you enabled static urls nased on DEBUG setting ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and set settings for static files.
Post collectstatic run you can actually see grapelli folder in your `STATIC ROOT` directory. Read the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) here for more details.

Make sure you have not added

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

to your urls under condition `DEBUG == True`.

Comment: I had not used static urls on my urls.py. But I had not used the `collectstatic` command. After running it all of grapelli's files and other stuff where moved inside a */static* directory located at the same level as my `manage.py`. What I have now is 

    * myServer 
    * myApp 
    * static

Yet it still complains about not finding the files, eg `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/grappelli/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.css `

Also please note that until now I had a file named *static* inside *myAPP* that had some templates, and it worked fine.

Comment: Ok it took me a while to understand what was going on. I just had to read all of the documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `ALLOWED_HOSTS` option in settings.py. You simply need to specify the allowed hosts for your website like:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['localhost']
```

or the simplest, but most insecure option:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
```

Comment: allowed host is to raise SuspiciousOperation not 404. Have a look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: sorry to ask this, but are you completely sure you are writing the domain which your website runs at?

Comment: I had this setting set correctly as I had been told that it might cause me issues. Si I am afraid that in this case this is not it.