# django1.9 does not load css from static admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.9

I am currently using django version 1.9. I try to create a new superuser then I run the server and try to login through the browser by navigating to 127.0.0.1:8000/admin, but the django admin page seem does not have any css. When i do inspect element in the browser itself I come to know that it link to two css files one is base.css and another one is login.css but those two contain nothing when i try to view it from the browser. After that i try to find those file in the installed django directory and i found out the base.css and login.css then i copy the all the code in that file to the base.css and login.css which i opened in the browser, then i got the beautiful django login page with proper css. I don't know what to do with this.

This is my console:

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aznS2.png)

I am using python 3.4.3 and django1.9.0. Thanks

Comment: What is the value of DEBUG in your settings file?

Comment: The value of DEBUG is True

Comment: Does it related to DEBUG value?

Comment: Yes it does. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py as below:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

and then try to run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: I think this method is going to work but not with the admin template.

Comment: @KenPhanith This config also works with admin templates. i added new variable in my answer. try it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django-rest-framework see [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#quickstart.).

You need to add it as,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'rest_framework',
)
```

and in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

It will automatically search and catch all the static files.