# Is it correct to add static link to my urlpatterns at urls.py

Tags: django, django-1.10

I am new at Django, and as I'm about to finalize my project, I toggled `DEBUG` from `True` to `False` to see if there are any actual errors. Now the static files are giving me an error `404` which I found the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail).

As a work around, I included this in my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I then did `python manage.py collectstatic`

Included this in my `settings.py`

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Now static files load whenever I toggle `DEBUG`. 
Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: what this tells us is that you are planning to use manage.py runserver (the django development server) in production. If so, you are definitely doing it wrong.

Comment: I see, so runserver is used for development purposes only? Are there any articles that you could refer to me for production purposes?

Comment: Found it! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist

Comment: glad you did. Please use gunicorn+nginx or mod_wsgi + httpd or something similar