# Django admin static files 404

Tags: python, django, file, static

I'm using Django version 1.10. Project work fine on Debug = True, but when I set it to False is not. Django just can't find static files.

My Django settings looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'master',
'update',
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    )

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

And the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^master/', include('master.urls')),
    url(r'^update/', include('update.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

uwsgi.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = %v
virtualenv      = %v/py
module          = go_conf.wsgi
master          = true
http            = :8000
vacuum          = true

buffer_size     = 64k
max-requests    = 100
daemonize       = %v/log.txt
```

I aslo used python manage.py collectstatic, and it collected everything but still not working.

I tried to solve this by reading other articles on this site, but nothing really worked for me.

Hope, that someone will at last help.

Comment: With debug turned off Django won't handle static files for you any more - your production web server (Apache or something) should take care of that. Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. However even when I'm using uwsgi this doesn't work. I edited my question and added uwsgi.ini file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the Django desing. A quote from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view) for *Static file development view*:

> This view will only work if DEBUG is True.
>
> That’s because this view is **grossly inefficient** and probably **insecure**. This is only intended for local development, and should never be used in production.

If you are setting `DEBUG=False` you are probably going to make it production. If so, your static files must be served by a webserver (eg. Nginx, Apache etc).

Comment: I just used uwsgi with http parameter. On my vps I have installed nginx.

Comment: If you want just uwsgi, then probaply `--static-map /static=/var/www/static` is the option for you. Details here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StaticFiles.html

Answer (score 1):

check the whitenoice library,
it works great for development and production environment
[Radically simplified static file serving for Python web apps](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html)