# Django 1.10 - why the app does not work with DEBUG=FALSE

Tags: python, django

I am completely beginner of Django / Python.

I wrote my app in Django 1.10, everything works good and now I would like to move the app at production server.

So, I have set the DEBUG on FALSE and suddenly whole app stopped working. It means, generally an app works, but static links doesn't work, the program does not see js, css files.

Do you know - why?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate or "too-broad" soon. However, don't be discouraged! If the answers (either here or in duplicate questions) don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Answer (score 1):

The development server knows how to serve static files but you have to set some settings for this to work in production. You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/#static-root-and-static-url).

That will also point you to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) page.

You need to do the following:

1. Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. In your settings file, define `STATIC_URL`.
3. Use the `static` template tag to build the URL for the given relative path. For example:

`{% load static %}
 <img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>`

4. Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For example `my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg`.
5. Set the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting in your settings file. For example:

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]`

Comment: Hi. I did it ,but I still can't run the app on production mode.

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/local/home/rob/testTool/static/',
]

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'testApp',
]

Comment: and an example path to css file:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.min.css' %}">

Comment: @Python-beg Can you give us an actual error message? "It still does not work" isn't something that we can work with.

Comment: the browser think that ,for an example, this link https://myPage.com/static/css/jquery-ui.min.css is an app and displays the communicate 'the page could not be found'