# Django 1.11 ManifestStaticFilesStorage - all hashed static files return 404

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have these settings in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I've run `collectstatic` and there are files in `/static/app/js` directory:

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.c9f5aeeca3ad.js
jquery-3.2.1.min.js
```

I'm just using Django's runserver to test this at the moment.

If I run with DEBUG = True, everything works, as the JS is fetched from `/static/app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`

If I run with DEBUG = False, all static files fail with 404. The JS URL is now `/static/app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.c9f5aeeca3ad.js`

The URL looks correct, the files exist, what could be causing this to fail?

My view includes:

```
{% load static %}

<script src="{% static 'app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Am I missing a setting?

(using Django 1.11, Python 3.6)

Comment: This only seems to be a problem with Django runserver, if I deploy the code to the server running Nginx/Gunicorn, the hashed files are served correctly. Is it just not possible using runserver?

Comment: Take a look at the answers in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail