# Django not serving media files when DEBUG is turned to False

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

Django is not serving my media files when `DEBUG = False`.

**Here is my code**:

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')
```

I've tried several things but none have worked.
Please help me if you know the answer to my problem!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail ?

Comment: The thing is that when I go live on heroku, the same problem occurs

Comment: @FantasmoClone27 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64218998/164374

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue.

In development, the Django development server serves the static files as documented in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/). If `settings.DEBUG` is `False` then static file serving by the development server stops. See this Stack Overflow post: [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files.
>
> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
>
> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.

For production, there are options for serving static files [as documented here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/)

I solved the issue of serving static files in production on an instance of [Dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku)—the smallest PaaS implementation you've ever seen—that is similar to Heroku.

I used a package called [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) that is discussed in [this blog post](http://andrealmar.com/serving-static-files-django-whitenoise).

I found Whitenoise to be the easiest solution to serving static files for a small Django application without having to configure a separate static file server.

Comment: I've followed step by step the post but it's still not working. I can successfully upload the files in local and in production but can't access them. This problem goes away when DEBUG is turned to False

Answer (score 0):

if you want to deploy your django project best practices please set `DEBUG=False` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['your_host']` and than collect your static and media files using command **`./manage.py collectstatic`**

Comment: this code in my computer is working, are you getting the error response what?

Comment: My problem is with the media files, which are located in the static files. Django is serving well static files, but not media files when DEBUG is turned to False

Answer (score 0):

As i can see your question is regarding media files but the answers are given about static files which are different if we see them at deployment level. For static files, you can simply use whitenoise. That will work perfectly. It will also work with media files but only when **DEBUG = True** and for shorter time(e.g, if you deploy your app on some platform which uses dynos like heroku, dynos refresh after a particular time. In heroku it is 30 min and after that media files will be deleted no matter whether the debug is set to true or false.) Which is not secure during deployment.So to make your media files working, you need some third party support to serve your media files to your site like Amazon S3 buckets which will store your media files and will serve them to your website.
Hope you got the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The Django documentation includes help about this ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)):

> ### Serving files uploaded by a user during development
>
> During development, you can serve user-uploaded media files from
> `MEDIA_ROOT` using the `django.views.static.serve()` view.
>
> This is not suitable for production use! For some common deployment
> strategies, see [How to deploy static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/static-files/deployment/).
>
> For example, if your `MEDIA_URL` is defined as `media/`, you can do this
> by adding the following snippet to your `ROOT_URLCONF`:
>
> ```
> from django.conf import settings
> from django.conf.urls.static import static
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
> ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
> ```
>
> **Note**
>
> This helper function works only in debug mode and only if the given
> prefix is local (e.g. media/) and not a URL (e.g.
> http://media.example.com/).

I think the step that you are missing is that you haven't modified your root URLs to point `MEDIA_URL` URLs to files found in `MEDIA_ROOT`.