# Mezzanine only loads admin pages on debug

Tags: python, django, heroku, mezzanine

I have a Mezzanine blog under development, hosted at Heroku.

While I have it on debug mode, by ensuring settings.py has DEBUG = True, everything works like a charm.

When I set it to false, any attempt to access admin gives me the generic error message. All other aspects of the site works fine, including blog posts I've made (with DEBUG = True) for testing.

I'm looking for any of two forms of help:

1. How could I get better debugging information while having DEBUG =
   False in settings.py?
2. Any hint or suggestion about what could be the problem.

Edit: My static files are being served with White Noise, locally, without any problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Comment: I'm serving my static files using White Noise, and it's working fine.

Comment: Check your logs

Answer (score 2):

A couple of months late, but for posterity: I found the same issue with Mezzanine 4.3.1 on Heroku. Without delving under the hood of the Mezzanine source code, using version 4.2.3 works fine.