# Static css and images not loading in django

Tags: django, nginx

I am new to Django. I ran the project in `Debug = True` at that time all CSS and images are loading properly. I try to change `Debug = False`. Now I face problems. Sometimes CSS is not loading . some times images are not loading. I have two images in the folder. One is loading and the other is not loading. In Develop mode `Debug = True` at that time is working properly.

I tried restarting `python3 manage.py runserver`, changing `STATIC_URL = "../../static/"` with no luck. Some images are loaded, some are not.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

mysite/static/images/icon/1.png //come
mysite/static/images/icon/2.png //not come
```

Both 1.png and 2.png are in folder. Sometimes CSS is loading, sometimes not.

I am using `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000` to start the project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the link that the friend posted, see the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/).

I use Django with NGINX with the following configuration:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Django will fetch the static files in URL `/static/` and the MEDIA files in URL `/media/`, so your NGINX has to be configured to search for those files:

```
location /static/ {
        alias   /your-project-folder/static/;
}

location /media/ {
        alias   /your-project-folder/media/;
}
```