# Do I have to run collectstatic every time to serve images when they are uploaded by user?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a web app that takes uploaded images and displays it to the user after registration. I have the media and static files separated in respective folders. When I run the app with debug as True, the images are served up to be displayed, but when debug is off, the images don't show. I have tried having the media folder under the static folder and running collectstatic and the images show. But when new images are uploaded, they are not served until the collectstatic is run again. Do I have to keep running collectstatic or there is better to have these folders separated and the images still show??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these folders should be separated. In Debug mode `runserver` [serves](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) these data for you:

> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will
>   be done automatically by runserver when **DEBUG** is set to True (see
>   django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
>
> This method is grossly **inefficient** and probably insecure, so it is **unsuitable for production**.

[In production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail) (DEBUG=False) you need to use more suitable tools, for instance, [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) in combination with [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/). Check out this [guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/) to understand how to properly set up your workflow in production.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Thing is I have read that documentation but it says nothing about media files, just statics files. Could you explain more on how using these tools would help?

Comment: @Praise `runserver` isn't desired for production usage, and in case of `DEBUG=False` won't server static(and media) files for you, but still, you could use `--insecure` option but there is strong advice not to do this. These tools do the job perfectly, `gunicorn` is just a production-ready replacement for `runserver` and `nginx` is used as a proxy.