# Cannot load static files in production after trying numerous solutions

Tags: python, django, static

I have moved my django project from development to my production server. After deployment I cannot view static files on my pages.

I know that django does not serve static files once debug is turned off and have tried using whitenoise to serve my static files.

**Attempt 1- WhiteNoise**

These are the changes that I made to settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

and wsgi.py:

```
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
...
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

and then running collectstatic. However my webpages still were not loading any of the static files.

**Attempt 2- Apache- mod_wsgi**

With the second attempt, I tried using apache+ mod_wsgi To be specific I connected to my VPS using terminal in cpanel installed apache2 and followed a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@miracleaayodele/deploy-django-on-apache-mod-wsgi-747c6e4db9d1).

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

created my conf file

```
sudo nano new_config.conf
```

added this to it

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 127.0.0.1
        ServerAlias localhost

        Alias /static /var/gradientboostmvp/static/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/gradientboostmvp/django_school/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/gradientboostmvp/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/gradientboostmvp
</VirtualHost>
```

enabled the newly created virtual host conf file

```
sudo a2ensite new_config.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

added my WSGIPythonPath in apache2.config

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/gradientboostmvp
```

saved the changed, but still couldn't load my static files

**Attempt 3- Import serve**

I also had a similar question that was closed as a duplicate. I tried the solutions offered in the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

```
from django.views.static import serve
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('', classroom.home, name='home'),
    path('about', classroom.about, name='about'),
    path('courses', classroom.courses, name='courses'),
    path('course_details', classroom.course_details, name='course_details'),
    path('static',serve {'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

Which then resulted in me getting an error message when I tried visiting my home page

> Incomplete response received from application

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you are using Apache to serve django, then why not use it serve static files as well. As per [**`documetation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), first you need to use [**`collectstatic`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) to store static files to a specific folder. For example in your settings if you have [**`STATIC_ROOT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#static-root) specified as:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/mysite.com/static/'
```

Then when you run collect static, the static files will be stored inside `/path/to/mysite.com/static/` directory.

Then add that path as alias to apache:

```
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/
```

Comment: could be mistaken but this is what tried under attempt 2

Comment: Did you ran collectstatic and also can you please verify that you have static files in your `/var/gradientboostmvp/static/` folder?

Comment: yes I ran collectstatic and have my static files in that path

Comment: I am not good at this, but can you try giving permission to `static` route like this: ```<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>```