# How can see where my site is looking for css and media

Tags: css, python-3.x, wagtail

I have implemented wagtail on my site and when I put it into production it is not finding the css or any images. I have run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and all of my css is in a directory called *static_files* in the same directory as *manage.py*.

In *base.py* I have:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)
....
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_media")
```

On my development site *BASE_DIR* is the directory with *static_files*, but it does not seem to pick it up on the production site.

Is there any way that I can test to see where the production version is looking for the css, e.g in the HTML?

[Edit]
I have looked at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail) and it does not address the core of my problem which is that certain essential code was not being called when DEBUG is set to False

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Comment: I would definitely check your browser's web inspector.

Comment: check the network tab in the browser webtool and look for the failing css request.

Comment: @gasman Yes indirectly. Thank you, I have posted my own answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the following code in *urls.py* in your project directory:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
...
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

For some reason this was in an **if** section under:

```
if setting.DEBUG = True
```

and I had DEBUG set to False. If I move it to the main body of the module, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In the references to the static assets in templates, be sure to use the `{% static ... %}` template tag ([reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)).  In the references to media files in templates, be sure to prefix with `{% get_media_prefix %}` ([reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix)).  Also, I typically use the same final designator for both `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` (i.e. `/static/`, not `/static/` for one and `static_files` for the other).  Here is how I declare these variables:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL.replace('/', ''))

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, MEDIA_URL.replace('/', ''))
```