# Django netbox Static Media Failure

Tags: python-3.x, django

Installing netbox using Django and nginx (https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/4-http-daemon/) and I encountered a problem as Django gives the following error for multiple files:

```
The following static media file failed to load: select2-bootstrap-0.1.0-beta.10/select2-bootstrap.min.css
```

It only works when i use `Python3 manage.py runserver --insecure`

Comment: Just checking - but is your SSL certificate properly installed and accessible to the Netbox user according to the instructions?

Comment: No i dont use SSL certificate

Comment: Perhaps follow the instructions to create one and try then. It might be looking for a cert to get the files

Comment: I made it with ssl but still get same problem , any help ?

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail