# uwsgi static files loading error form django (react and webpack)

Tags: django, webpack, django-rest-framework, uwsgi, wsgi

My app consists of django and react, which at the end is bundled to static (.js) file.
My goal is to setup a nginx for it, but for now I just want to run in uwsgi to see if it works.
Aaaaand it does not work at all. I belive there is a issue with loading this bundle file which webpack is compiling.

Connection to uwsgi works, server is up and running, but when connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080 I get (in Mozilla):

```
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/frontend/main.js” 
was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch 
(X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

# and another

GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/frontend/main.js

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 3277
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Vary: Origin
```

Similar topic I found: [Difference between static STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT on Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687927/difference-between-static-static-url-and-static-root-on-django)

and this: [Django + React The resource was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555499/django-react-the-resource-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-text-html-mismatch)

But messing with `python manage.py collectstatic` resolved nothing.

I have this lines of code to manage static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join('/app/label_it/front/static/frontend/')
```

And this is how I start my uwsgi connection:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8080 --master --enable-threads --module label_it.wsgi
```

Beside `collectstatic` I've tried messing with `<script src"static_file_path"></script>` this static path with:

```
<script src="../../static/frontend/main.js"></script>

# and

<script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
```

Which result in nothing.

Any clues appreciated !

EDIT:

My file structure:

[image: file structure]

Comment: Are you able to include a screenshot of what your django project file structure looks like. I want to see where the react front-end files are stored in relation to the django app please

Comment: @Danoram updated. In `/front/static/frontend` dir is the bundled static file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just did some testing with my own server and django project to confirm my suspicion and I've come to the following conclusion: This error will happen if the path to the static file doesn't exist. Meaning that uwsgi cannot find this `main.js` file with the settings you have.

My suggestion would be to do the following to ensure your static files are being served correctly in a way that django knows where to look.

By default django searches inside each installed app for a `static` folder to find static assets. Because your project is not setup that way you have to specify additional directories where static files live.

This is what `STATICFILES_DIRS` is for.

In your `settings.py` put the following

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS  = [
    BASE_DIR / 'label_it/front/static'
]
```

This will make all files inside `label_it/front/static` discoverable to django.

Now this means that

`<script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>`

will (hopefully) work.

additionally, remember to include your static urls in your `urls.py` file if you haven't already.

`urls.py`

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

# static content urls
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

---

Sidenote: `STATIC_ROOT` is intended to be the location where all static files will be collected to when you run `python manage.py collectstatic`.

As such it should be an empty directory, preferably in the root of your django project.

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_collected')`

The name of the folder doesn't really matter and I've used `static_collected` as an example.

If you run the command hopefully you'll see all the files in `label_it/front/static/` copied there.

Comment: Yes, You are right. With some hard debugging I did manage to fix this issue along with setting `--static-map` as uwsgi cmd flag.

Comment: after dealing with this issue, even more interesting occured. My page loads blank, even tho http request for page is `200 OK` and received proper html. If You;d like to help, here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247510/django-not-loading-js-static-file-in-production?noredirect=1#comment117122945_66247510

Comment: Hey, will you please look at my question. I am having the same problem but I am unale to solve the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73437331/mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-mime-type-and-strict-mime