# django not loading .js static file in production

Tags: python, html, django, wsgi

I have a hard time setting up my static files for Django to load.
My UWSGI connection is on point, and i receive `http 200 OK` with `index.html`, but
`<scipt type="application/javascript" src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></scipt>` gives me nothing. It'strange, because `127.0.0.1:8000/static/main.js` actually return `main.js`.

I think there is a problem with loading this file into this template. Any ideas whats wrong?

(I run the whole app in docker container)

My `index.html` template to load:

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Label It</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
    />
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="app">
      </div>
    </div>
    <scipt type="application/javascript" src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></scipt>
  </body>
</html>
```

part from `settings.py`:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/vol/web/static'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/vol/web/media'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/vol/web/static/frontend'
]
```

Comment: Django does not serve static files in production. You are expected to set up a web server for that.

Comment: @KlausD. Well, You are right, but it needs a proper connection with `collectstatic`. Do You have any idea why there is no page view even tho uwsgi outputs no error ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></scipt>`

to

`src="{% static "main.js" %}"></scipt>`

My hunch is if `127.0.0.1:8000/static/main.js` works it must mean the `'frontend/'` part is redundant.

Comment: It did not solve the issue, but strangely the output is the same (and file availible in `/static/main.js`), no error.
Tried to change `src="{% "main.js" %}` and got `500 server error`. Then `frontend` is redundant.

Comment: Actually it might mean it wasn't redundant. the server error might be django not being able to resolve the url.

Comment: thank You very much for help. After all, my stupid a** wrtoe `<scipt>` rather then `<script>`, Any without any html syntax error in vscode I've spend 2 days for research

Comment: oh dear! not even I noticed that! frustrating