# How can I host my Django website on a local server?

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment

I have created a website with Django, running locally in a linux virtual machine on ip adress `192.168.0.111:8000`. Now I want to make this website available for the public, hosted on my own machine.

I have a webproxy (NginxProxyManager) running on my server on ip adress 192.168.0.118:7818 which handles all my other static websites.

I can route my domain name `https://django.example.com` to `192.168.0.111:8000` in my webproxy and everything works in `DEBUG = True`, but i know this is not the way to do it, and `DEBUG = False` does not serve static files properly.

How can i do this? All websites about this topic are takling about publishing to Heroku or something else, but i want to host it locally. Thank you!

Edit: I tried to serve static files from my webproxy like this and it worked fine

```
location /static/ {
    alias /config/static/; # local path on the webproxy server
}
```

but i'd really like to serve the files from the same computer that is hosting the Django website.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to serve static files with `DEBUG=False` and using the development server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Not Applying CSS File From App on 404 Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63116823/django-not-applying-css-file-from-app-on-404-page)