# Static Files Not Loading Django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I am following a tutorial, and I copied the [repo](https://github.com/zinmyoswe/Django-Ecommerce), Add for some reason, the static files will not load.

This is my folder structure involves having my templates file in my main app and my static files are outside this folder. In the main folder (Django-ecommerce) sitting where my main app is.

settings.py

```
import os

ENVIRONMENT = os.getenv('ENVIRONMENT', 'development')

DEBUG = False
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxx'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_countries',
    'core'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'demo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'templates'
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')

if ENVIRONMENT == 'production':
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
    SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
    SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
    SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000
    SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = []
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend'
)

SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Provider specific settings
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        # For each OAuth based provider, either add a ``SocialApp``
        # (``socialaccount`` app) containing the required client
        # credentials, or list them here:
        'APP': {
            'client_id': '123',
            'secret': '456',
            'key': '666'
        }
    }
}

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4
```

Header.html

```
{% load static %}
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png"
    href="{% static 'images/icons/favicon.png' %}"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'fonts/themify/themify-icons.css' %}"
  />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'fonts/Linearicons-Free-v1.0.0/icon-font.min.css' %}"
  />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'fonts/elegant-font/html-css/style.css' %}"
  />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'vendor/animate/animate.css' %}"
  />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css' %}"
  />
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css' %}"
  />
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'vendor/select2/select2.min.css' %}"
  />
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css' %}"
  />
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'vendor/slick/slick.css' %}"
  />
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'vendor/lightbox2/css/lightbox.min.css' %}"
  />
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/util.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.css">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
```

And My `base.html`

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" />
{% include "header.html" %}

  <title>{% block head_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  {% block extra_head %} {% endblock %}
  <style type="text/css">
    .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da !important;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
  </style>
  <body class="animsition">
    {% include "nav.html"%}
    <div class="mt-2">
      {% if messages %} {% for message in messages %}
      <div
        class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show"
        role="alert"
      >
        {{ message }}

        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          data-dismiss="alert"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% endfor %} 
    {% endif %} 

    {% block content %} 
  \
    {% endblock content %}

     {% block extra_body %} 
     {% endblock %} 

    {% include "footer.html"%} 
    {% include "script.html"%}

    {% block extra_scripts %}
    {% endblock extra_scripts %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried moving my static folder into my main app folder but it still does not work.

Comment: When you change **Debug = True** if it's working maybe you need to see this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Comment: I have spent 2 hours on this website looking for the answer!!! i feel so foolish. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help you.