# Django static image not loading on setting debug=False

Tags: python, html, django

How do I load images in debug=False for testing purposes? Below is my code for your reference.

```
<img src="/static/b_icon.png" alt="Brand Icon" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
```

Comment: did you check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7639983/10754535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
<img src="/static/b_icon.png"
```

This is right:

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static 'b_icon.png' %}
```

Just take a moment to read carefully [Managing static files, Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) docs and follow all steps.