# copying to STATIC_ROOT using collectstatic but image not visible

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

Need to access static files from common directory as suggested in

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

command, `python manage.py collectstatic`

copies to STATIC_ROOT but when referring to it in html, it throws error

```
Not Found: /static/teststatic/images/product-5.jpg
```

How to make it work with files from the STATIC_ROOT location ?

I have tried this and has worked

```
<img src="{% static 'teststatic/static/teststatic/images/product-5.jpg' %}" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'teststatic'

urlpatterns = [
    path('tstatic/', views.tstatic, name='tstatic'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.


def tstatic(request):
    return render(request, 'tstatic.html', {})
```

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True
.
.
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('testcss', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'testcss', 'static', 'testcss')),
    ('helpdesk', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'helpdesk', 'static', 'helpdesk')),
    ('teststatic', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'teststatic', 'static', 'teststatic')),
    (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'))
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

**tstatic.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Image</h2>
<img src="{% static 'teststatic/images/product-5.jpg' %}" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">

</body>
</html>
```

**Error :**

```
2021-04-27 12:42:47,744: Not Found: /static/teststatic/images/product-5.jpg
```

Comment: Please show your status DEBUG in your `settings.py`, false or true? If it's False maybe you need to see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail

Comment: in settings.py, debug = True,