# User uploaded images not serve after debug=false in django?

Tags: django

install whitenoise urls.py setting

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, }), ]
```

also configure static root and static url in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / '/static/images/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In urls.py file:
add this:

```
from django.views.static import serve
```

and add those two urlpatterns:

```
re_path('media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
re_path('static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT})
```