# request media files in django when the debug is false

Tags: python, django, web, django-settings, django-media

i tried to set media root and media url in but when the debug is false don't return anything

**settings.py**

```py
...
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    '0.0.0.0',
    ...
]
...
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

**urls.py**

```py
...
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
...
```

What should i do to return media files in my projects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Comment: please check my answer here, good luck https://stackoverflow.com/a/73928488/18806558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer

**urls.py**

```py
...
from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.static import serve
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    ...
]
...

# urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
...
```

This `re_path` function will can request all the files in the `MEDIA_ROOT` in **settings.py**

Answer (score 0):

When `DEBUG=False`, local files will not be accessible. You need to try any online storage for static and media files e.g. AWS S3 bucket etc.

Guide:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer
I want to set my host to be as storage also for media folder