# Nginx server does not recognize static Django files

Tags: django, nginx

I'm setting up an AWS server and I finished the tutorial provided by DigitalOcean, however my server doesn't recognize my static files and displays a page with styles only via CDN (Tailwind)

Nginx Configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  xxxxxxxxxxxxx;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/ubuntu/Filmes/static;
   }

    location /media {
        root /home/ubuntu/Filmes;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

}
```

My project `settings.py`:

```
import os

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR / "static")
```

Structure when running `python manage.py collectstatic`:

```
- static
|------ admin
|------ css
|------ images
|------ js
|------ staticfiles.json
```

Tutorial:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: You have to reboot system

Comment: Thanks but it was worth the try

Comment: Try appending a slash after `location /static` and after `alias  /home/ubuntu/Filmes/static` that it looks like: `location /static/ {alias  /home/ubuntu/Filmes/static/;}` then restart nginx. `alias` works different than `root` and needs a trailing `/`

Comment: I copied exactly as you suggested: `location /static/ {alias /home/ubuntu/Filmes/static/;}` and still nothing

Comment: So I went to look in my project directory. And have two parts: static and staticfiles. I tried staticfiles and it worked. I don't know why it created two parts. But thanks for the help!

Comment: if you but Debug=False, please check there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73926690/user-uploaded-images-not-serve-after-debug-false-in-django/73928488#73928488

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it. But it's a server for testing, I'm going to kill the machine after finishing.