# Why is the CSS not loading in the Django admin panel?

Tags: css, django, admin, loading, production

when i am on my local host the css is loading but when i am on server  then it is not and i am not using any static files in my project and debug is also set to False

I have tried setting debug = False and collect static files.

Comment: Are u using nginx or any other web server before django

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Answer (score 0):

If the static files are not loaded you may miss one of these steps:

> 1. define `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` in `settings.py`. for example:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATICFILES_DIRS=(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/assets/'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

> 2. define `static` in `urls.py`. for example

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api_app.urls')),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) \
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> 3. Collect static files in the defined static directory:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

> 4. check your server's public directories.

if you are using some shared host as your project server keep in mind that the static files should be in a public directory(like `public_html`) to be reachable by Django.