# django admin broken in development mode

Tags: django

I am a newbie in django (not in programming though) and following the w3school tutorials. When running the django admin at `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` and in **development mode**, I end up with a layout problem which seems to be related to how the django css files are accessed.

[image: Overview of the problem]

I have a clean and new django install.

I have googled the problem and all that I have found are posts solving the same problem in production mode (not in development mode) or posts dated more than 10 years.

Does anyone understand what is going on and how to fix the problem?

Comment: Update your question witht terminal logs and settings file

Comment: check if STATIC_URL in root_project/settings.py is set correctly if so can you share your settings file and your django version

Comment: I would check if maybe `DEBUG=False` in settings.py, as per what it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @Martin in the comments, this is all related to `DEBUG` being set to  `FALSE` in the `setting.py` file. This solves the problem in development.

This is not a clean and definitive solution though, especially for production were you should specify your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and install a 3rd party lib to handle the static files, a common choice being **WhiteNoise** but there are many others.