# How to correctly display static files in Django when debug = False?

Tags: python, django, web, backend

what should I do if I used a command python manage.py collectstatic and don’t understand what needs to be done in order for static files to be located and displayed, i get only 404 when i try to load server and my css also dont working
my settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']




PATH_TO_YOUR_STATIC_FOLDER= 'man/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "man/static",
    PATH_TO_YOUR_STATIC_FOLDER,
]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"






# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

[my files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhAa8.png)

maybe i need to edit STATICFILES_DIRS?

i was trying to change STATICFILES_DIRS in settings, but nothing

Comment: I suggest you start at the docs, these tell you how to manage this for production https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)