# Jpegs in Django-wiki

Tags: django, jpeg, python-imaging-library, wiki

I'm trying to get django-wiki running.
It works well so far, except I can't display .jpeg images.

At first I had trouble when only importing jpeg files in the webapp.
I fixed this modifying setup.py of PIL's setup.py as follows:

```
JPEG_ROOT = libinclude("/usr/lib")

# Line 214
add_directory(library_dirs, "/usr/lib")
add_directory(library_dirs, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
```

Jpeg libs I have currently installed:

```
libjpeg-progs
libjpeg62:amd64
libjpeg62-dev:amd64
libjpeg8:amd64
libopenjpeg2:amd64
```

After install PIL with pip install PIL, I get this output which doesn't look that bad, at least I thought so

```
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
```

No error messages (and no "decoder ntót available") and I can view the images properly on my server, which means upload works great. But in the wiki only the file names are shown and when I click on them I get

> "This image failed to load."

Could someone please help me? I can't find any error output (debug mode is activated).

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling software! You need to install development libraries for these things to compile, e.g. `apt-get install libjpeg-dev`.

Also, install Pillow, it has less chances of failure to compile - `pip install pillow`.

Comment: @forethinker you can try looking if the required images are in fact in your filesystem and readable, furthermore that sorl.thumbnail is writing thumbnails in your media/cache folder.. if you can't find the thumbnails then something is wrong with sorl or Pillow in the thumbnail creation process.

Comment: Turns out the routing for django's static file was the problem for me. Here is [the solution that worked me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root)

Comment: @forethinker yes, but *media*, not *static* :)