# Issue in loading user uploaded images in Django

Tags: django, django-media, django-mediagenerator

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'photo.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^photo/', include('photo.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
 url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static',
        (r'media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```

Settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'E:/photo/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

When i try to access user uploaded images it gives me following error.

```
Using the URLconf defined in photo.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/doc/
^admin/
media/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, images/about-landscapes-nature.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

What am i doing wrong?
User uploaded images are getting stored in photo\media\images

Following is the directory structure in my Win7

```
photo
    media
    photoapp
        models.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

Comment: I tried answer in this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root by @micah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this'll fix all your problems, but `MEDIA_URL` needs a trailing slash, so it should be:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Woah...!!! This actually solved my problem. Such a silly mistake... Thanks... @shapiromatron