# django images upload dir and template handling

Tags: django, image, view

I have some model with a FileField() looks like this:

```
image = models.FileField(upload_to='/Users/john/projects/MyDjangoApp/foobars/images/')
```

So foobar is some module from MyDjangoApp.
In future there comes another module like barfoos and this will have an own images folder.

What I don't understand is how to handle this in the template.
Now there stand something like:

```
<td><img src="{{ foobar.image.url }}" height="350" width="350"></td>
```

So there stand the following:

```
/Users/john/projects/MyDjangoApp/foobars/images/71RkbKwBxnL._SL1004_.jpg
```

But it must be, something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobars/images/71RkbKwBxnL._SL1004_.jpg
```

All url patterns I find only handle this if the images hosted in /MyDjangoApp/static/images, I wish to handle the files in /MyDjangoApp/foobars/images and later /MyDjangoApp/barfoos/images.

Ho to handle this in Django.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `upload_to` argument should be a path relative to your `MEDIA_ROOT` setting. The url that you'll use to access the file is the same relative path appended to your `MEDIA_URL` setting.

Also check out the documentation on [`FileField`s and `ImageField`s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) and on the [`MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root)

Comment: Thats right, but I will multi MEDIA_ROOT and on this multi MEDIA_URL settings, how can I implement this. Both of my "packeges" have own MEDIA_ROOT paths, thats why in the model upload_to is an absolute path.

Comment: Now I have the following in the settings: MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'   and MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/john/projects/MyDjangoApp/' in the model: image = models.ImageField(upload_to='foobars/images') the file url i get: http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobars/images/71bYTz3ti6L._SL1200_.jpg  BUT 404 But the images still there upload works fine...  Thanks for every help!

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root) for help with your 404 error. In general it's better to use a relative url, so `MEDIA_URL = '127.0.0.1:8000/'` becomes `MEDIA_URL = '/'`.