# ImageField in Django 1.5.4 -- dealing with the images' paths

Tags: python, django, html, django-models, django-admin

I am using Django 1.5.4 and I have a project with the following structure:

```
django_site
    -django_site
    -books # the app
        -media
            -images
                -books
                -authors
        -static
            -images
    -templates
```

This is the necessary code:

```
# settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = '/root/django_site/books/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/books/")

# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^books/$', 'books.views.get_all_books'),
)
```

My problem is that, after adding the image via the admin site, if I click on the image link below the upload button a `404` page shows up, complaining the path does not exist.

The request URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/books/media/images/book/out_of_control_1.JPG` but in fact I want the result to be `/root/django_site/books/media/images/out_of_control_1.JPG`.

How do I fix that? Looking forward to your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to use the developpement server, I think your issue is related to this one : [Django MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root)

As explained in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5518073/2844093), you have to set up a specific URL pattern for media handling when debug is set to True.

You can also have a look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) regarding this question.

Comment: Yeah the Django Docs helped me but the most popular answer in the first link. Thanks a lot!