# Django admin not serving static files?

Tags: python, django, static, admin

`Django 1.6`

I'm having trouble serving my static files for my Django Admin.

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'collection.views.index', name='home'),
    url(r'^collection/', include('collection.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/',    include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
)
```

**settings.py**

```
...
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/me/projectdir/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/me/projectdir/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
...
```

**template (base.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-us'>
<head>
<title>Mysite</title>

{% load static %}
{% block links %}
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootswatch-simplex.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "favicon.ico" %}">
{% endblock %}

<script src="{% static "lib/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{% filter escapejs %}{% static "admin/" %}{% endfilter %}";</script>
</head>
...
```

Django is serving my admin OK, just without static files: CSS, JS, etc.

Static files for my public-facing pages work fine.

If I change `STATIC_URL` to `'/static/'`, then the *opposite* is true: the admin is fine, but my public pages lose their static files.

Here's the weirdest part.  If I "view source" of my admin pages in my browser, it shows the correct URL for static pages, for example:

```
/static/admin/css/base.css
```

But if I actually follow the link, it changes it to this:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/static/admin/css/base.css
```

I think it's checking for static files relative to `localhost:8000/admin/static/` instead of just `localhost:8000/static/`. It adds an extra "`admin`" level to the url, like `static` is part of the domain.  I just can't figure out how to get rid of it.

I have tried `collectstatic`, but it doesn't help.  The static files are in my static directory, they're just not being served. I can type in, say, `http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css` and I get the right CSS file (in plaintext). The files are there. I bet something is wrong with my configuration.

I've emptied my caches, restarted my dev server, etc.  No beans.

ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code in your template where you're trying to access your static files?

Comment: You don't need urlpatterns in urls.py. Try removing that and check out by setting STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: @Alex, I appreciate your hunch.  I updated my code above.  I also tried removing `{% filter escapejs %}{% static "admin/" %}{% endfilter %}` to no avail.

Comment: @SudipKafle, I'm not sure what you mean?  Do you mean to just have a set of `url(...)`s without any `urlpatterns` wrappers?

Comment: you don't need the extra code after if debug==TRUE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  There was some confusion in my settings files, and I did not have `STATICFILES_DIRS` correctly set.

In the end, I implemented the version-controlled settings files discussed in [Two Scoops of Django 1.6](http://pydanny.com/announcing-two-scoops-of-django-1.6.html), with this in my `settings`:

```
from unipath import Path

BASE_DIR         =  Path(__file__).ancestor(3)
MEDIA_ROOT       =  BASE_DIR.child('media')
STATIC_ROOT      =  BASE_DIR.child('static')

TEMPLATE_DIRS    = (
    BASE_DIR.child('templates'),
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    BASE_DIR.child('myapp').child('static'),
)

STATIC_URL         = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL          = '/media/'
```

With this, my static files are being served correctly, both in admin and without.  My media files, on the other hand, did not work without changing my `urls.py` in development, according to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root).  I did not have to do the same for my static files.

Anyways, I hope this helps anyone else banging their head against this particular wall.

Answer (score 12):

Use `django-admin.py collectstatic` or go to `~/django/contrib/admin/static` and copy the admin folder(which contains the static files) and paste them into your project's static directory.

****EDIT****

A desperate or clumsy solution you can try for: change your STATIC_URL to '/static/', as from question I saw this:

> If I change STATIC_URL to '/static/', then the opposite is true: the
>   admin is fine, but my public pages lose their static files.

Then check with `inspect element/firebug`, see what urls are being served in public pages. Probably a '/' missing or added a '/'. Adjust it, and see if it works.

Comment: the static files are in my static directory, they're just not being served.  I can type in, say, `http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css` and I get the right CSS file (in plaintext).  The files are there.  Thanks, though... I updated my question to reflect your idea.

Comment: if you are getting the right css by http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css then your statics are being served properly. Use firebug and see what urls are you getting for your css files, then adjust them accordingly :)

Comment: thanks, yes that's what I'm trying to get across.  I have been spending time with Firebug.  I don't know how to 'adjust them accordingly.'

Comment: well I answered about that in the answer's edit section. Check what is missing/added. probably a '/'. Then change in your template accordingly, for example href="{% static 'foo/bar.css' %}" to href="{% static '/foo/bar.css' %}"

Comment: Firebug shows the correct relative link.  It seems Django is serving static files according to the `localhost:8000/admin/` root instead of just `localhost:8000/`.  If so, don't know how to fix.  I updated my question.  Any idea?

Comment: I've been adding random `/`s everywhere trying to fix this... hasn't worked.  Thanks though.

Comment: From 'templates/admin/base.html', you will see in line 3: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}" />, so admin css being served like localhost:8000/admin/ is the way admin template should be serving css. And random '/' won't work actually :(.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53932/discussion-between-ruddra-and-niteshade)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue for two times. 
The way i solved it was by pasting the static files of admin into static folder mentioned in the code -

```
cp -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin /home/ec2-user/mywork-Deployment/mywork/static
```

This one definitely works and saves a lot of time and troubles. 
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

First You need to try:`python manage.py collectstatic`
then u got any errors just follow these steps

**step1**
**[Remove these code from you**r `settings.py`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V9YS.png)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/home/uour project/src/project name/static/',
)  //remove these lines
```

**step2**

Replace with it [replace with these codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nXev.png)

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') //add these line
```

**step3**
open terminal and type:`python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, I will share what the issue was with my code. Probably my stupid mistake but may save someone's time:

So, basically. my `settings.py` variables were something like this:

```py
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/"
STATIC_URL = f"https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/"
```

I inspected the admin page css `src` tags and found out the URLs were like this:
(Notice two forward slashes in the URL) 
`https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com//admin/css/login.css`.

So I changed my variables slightly and everything loaded fine.

```py
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com"
STATIC_URL = f"https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/"
```

That corrected the faulty URLs and static files loaded perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The way that worked out for me was I referenced the static admin files in my settings.py file. I hope this helps someone :)

```
'./static/admin/',
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i only set debug to True and they loaded , strange but worked somehow