# How to serve media file when runserver --insecure?

Tags: django

Is there any way to serve Media files when `runserver --insecure`

It serves only css and js and image but i need to serve media file with ...

[They](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-option---insecure) mention it's not possible with `cachefile` but no word about media.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell it to serve your media files. In your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG == False:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
)
```

Comment: Note: Django is getting friendlier about serving staticfiles via runserver for development, but media appears to still require this update (I'd only use this when DEBUG is True, not False).

Comment: In my case, after changing 'django.views.static.serve' into serve, It did work perfectly. Before changing it, You should import some modules by `from django.views.static import serve`  and  `from django.conf import settings`,
`from django.conf.urls import url`

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve

def static(prefix, view=serve, **kwargs):
    return [
        re_path(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % re.escape(prefix.lstrip('/')), view, kwargs=kwargs),
    ]
```

Then in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```