# MEDIA_URL Page Not Found when DEBUG is False

Tags: django

I'm using Python 2.7, Django 1.8 and apache server on my project. When I use `DEBUG=True`, on my develop server, uploaded images viewed very well on template, but when `DEBUG=False`,  i get a 404 error. However static files work very well.

My setting.py look so:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The urls.py looks like on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root):

```
if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What  i should change to make my media files work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With debug turned off Django won't handle static files for you any more - your production web server (Apache or something) should take care of that.
If you still need to server static locally (e.g. for testing without debug) you can run devserver in insecure mode:

```
manage.py runserver --insecure
```

Comment: I didn't mention about that i use apache server and my develop server now is a production server.