# Django - Image Uploads save to correct location, but cannot be displayed

Tags: python, django, image

I have been developing my own website in Django and have come across an issue,

I have a model:

```
class Text_Image_Page(TrainingModulePage):
          page_num = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
          title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
          text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
          image_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
          image = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, default = 'null')
          training_module = models.ForeignKey(TrainingModule, related_name='text_image_pages',  null=True)
          def __str__(self):
               return "Image Page"
```

I am using a modelForm to create this model, and everything works fine until I try to display the model in my template.

My Media Root in my settings.py is

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/superchem_media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/anthonycalab/webapps/superchem_static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/anthonycalab/webapps/superchem_media/'
```

The images are being correctly uploaded to the media root as I can see they exist via filezilla however when I go to display my image in my template:

```
<img src={{t.image.url}}  alt="{{t.image_desc}}" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

It doesn't display the image, futhermore if I load the images direct link I get a 404 error with the following message:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:             http://anthonycalab.webfactional.com/home/anthonycalab/webapps/superchem_media/41WKTB25KsL._SY395__mNsiAbb.jpg
Using the URLconf defined in superchem.urls, Django tried these URL    patterns, in this order:
^training_modules/
^admin/
^accounts/
^superchem\_media\/(?P<path>.*)$
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL,      home/anthonycalab/webapps/superchem_media/41WKTB25KsL._SY395__mNsiAbb.jpg,       didn't match any of these.
```

Any Idea's what I could be doing incorrectly?

EDIT:

The problem has been narrowed down to:

{{t.image.url}} = /home/anthonycalab/webapps/superchem_media/41WKTB25KsL._SY395__mNsiAbb.jpg

when I want

/media/[imagelink].jpg

Comment: Can you show your url settings? Looks like you don't set media url 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root

Comment: `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns(settings.STATIC_URL)`


The problem is:

image.url is giving me:

/home/anthonycalab/webapps/superchem_media/image.jpg

instead of:

media/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

add media url in main urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings


admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('home.urls')),

]

urlpatterns += patterns('',
                        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),
                        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),
                        )
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: This still gives me the same issue.

{{img.url}} = /home/anthonycalab/webapps/superchem_media/img.jpg 

were it should just give me /media/img.jpg

Comment: Is there a way to return only the image name?

e.g image1.jpg

Comment: did you added this code in your settings.

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
        '-------------------'
        'django.core.context_processors.media',
        'django.core.context_processors.static',
        '-----------'
    )

Comment: it will return the filename import os
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    ...
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)

Answer (score 0):

```
settings.py

import os

def root(x):
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..',x)

MEDIA_ROOT = root('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = root('staticstorage')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    root('static'),
)


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    '-------------------'
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    '-----------'
)

urls.py 

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += patterns('',
                        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),
                        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),
                        )
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```