# Image and Sound (Media) not showing on django

Tags: python, django, media

I am trying to play an audio in django but it cannot find the audio file. I have setup the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT but it still doesn't work. Please help me.
Below is the code snippet

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$',home),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

home.html

```
{% extends "layout/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>  Sound Assessment Toolset  </h1>
    <audio src="{{MEDIA_URL}}master_sound/piano.mp3"></audio>
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/batman.jpg"/>
{% endblock %}
```

[Image of Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA2I9.png)

the log file :

```
Django version 1.8.7, using settings 'Sound_Assessment.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8800/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[17/Jun/2016 15:18:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 746
[17/Jun/2016 15:18:43] "GET /images/batman.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2321
[17/Jun/2016 15:18:43] "GET /master_sound/piano.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 2336
[17/Jun/2016 15:18:43] "GET /images/batman.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2321
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from this thread
[Django MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root)

What I did is added this line "django.core.context_processors.media" in settings.py inside Template Context_Processor.

Here

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                 ...
                 'django.core.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add media template context processor in your settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then you will have `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` in your template.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually requesting those elements under MEDIA_URL, as you can see from the log file.

That's because you haven't actually passed those variables to the template, so they are being ignored.

Comment: Hi I am new to django, can you please give an example of how it can be done ?