# django 1.10 media images don't show

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-media, django-1.10

I have had django media images working in an existing django 1.7 project by adding the following to site urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patters(
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
)
```

This url structure doesn't work in django 1.10 and so I changed it to the reccommended here [Django MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root):

```
urlpatterns = [

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**This fails to render any uploaded media images.  Is there an equivalent media url patter for django 1.10 I can use?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: 
([Django docs 1.10 Serving files uploaded by a user during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/))

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

OR you can use this (if you only want it in development with the Debug = True in you'r settings): [Django docs 1.10 Serving files in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/views/)

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
```

For me the **{{ MEDIA_URL }}** didn't work anymore in my template file, I used the **{% get_media_prefix %}**:

Ex.:

```
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ product.image }}">
```