# Django 1.10 media (FileField) 404

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

My first question ever, so go easy. I'll give as much detail as possible.

**My setup**

- django 1.10 (I know, I need to upgrade)
- python 3.5.[something]
- postgres DB
- gunicorn
- nginx

**The problem and what I've tried**

The problem is that I pulled a recent commit that was working fine locally and suddenly none of a model's images, which previously rendered fine, are working - I'm getting 404s for all of them. I've tried the following:

- Checking out previous commits
- Restarting gunicorn (`sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`)
- Restarting nginx
- Restarting postgresql
- Using `python manage.py shell` to access objects and check that they're still associating with a URL to the file

My code works when run locally - none of the uploaded images/files are causing 404s. As with my production environment, the `logos` folder sits in the main directory of my project, rather than being appended to a `media` folder (which other answers and the django docs suggested would be the case - this could be a red herring though).

My browser console shows the 404s and that it's trying to fetch from `<domain.com>/media/logos/<filename>`, even though they're stored (I've checked the file structure) in `<project_folder>/logos/<filename>` (i.e. without the `media` folder), but this was never previously a problem. Again, locally this is also the case but is completely fine.

**My code and stuff**

In my **models.py** I have this field:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    ...
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to='logos/', blank=True)
```

...which I then render in my HTML file with:

```
<img class="..." src="{{ thing.logo.url }}>
```

...which, again, is how django docs says to do it (rather than hard-coding a URL). I read in the docs that the file is stored as part of the object in the database, so referring to a filepath with filename wouldn't necessarily work (or something similar), therefore that this is the best option.

As far as I can see my urls are set up fine:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

...as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311816/django-1-10-media-images-dont-show) (and probably others).

In **settings.py** no filepaths or URLs are hard-coded: they're all relative to the `os.path...`.

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` and `MEDIA_ROOT` is unset (default is '')

I can't think of any other information that would be helpful, but if there is then let me know. Please help! I currently have a live website with ugly alt-text :(

Comment: What are the values of yout `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` settings?

Comment: `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` and I haven't set `MEDIA_ROOT`, as the default is blank.

Comment: The `static(...)` only works in development. In production you should configure your server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) to serve the files. See the [example for Apache and modwsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files).

Comment: It would be a good idea to set `MEDIA_ROOT` instead of using the empty string. Normally you would set it to a location outside of your project, since those files should not be checked in.

Comment: Would that affect whether or not I get 404s though? After all, it used to work without issue. I appreciate that it's best practice though @Alasdair

Comment: As I said, in production you should configure your server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) to serve the files. You haven't shown any configuration that would serve the files. Perhaps you had `DEBUG=True` before.

Comment: `DEBUG=False` and has done for a while. However, I have just checked Nginx config and `location /static/ ...` is set but not `location /media/ ...`. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. You need to configure Nginx to serve the media files.

Comment: Still doesn't explain the change from it working before the most recent commit, but I'll check and report back. I'll also look into folder permissions issues, as I've seen [indications](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-unable-to-server-static-and-media-images?answer=27666) that that could be an issue too. Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The static(...) only works in development. In production you should configure your server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) to serve the files. See the example for Apache and modwsgi. – Alasdair [Jan 9 at 22:12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176885/django-1-10-media-filefield-404#comment83334915_48176885)

Thanks @Alasdair for your above comment - unfortunately I can't mark it as the answer, but it led to it.

I hadn't setup Nginx to handle media files - only static files. So my Nginx conf file now looks like this:

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/<path>/<to>/<folder>;
}

location /media/ {
    root /home/<path>/<to>/<folder>;
}
```

My Django app was then uploading files to a slightly unexpected location, so I had to copy those files across to the correct media file location and set that right.