# Accessing non-static images in Django?

Tags: python, django

I don't want to store images in static for this Django project because the user will be able to change them from the admin panel.

My code looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<img class="img-responsive" src="/galleryimg/first.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Where /galleryimg/ is a folder in the root directory of the project, and "first.jpg" is the file that I want to serve.

However, this does not load. How can I get it to load?

Comment: You need to configure your media url, which is intended for exactly what you are trying to do here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a django media url

In your **setting.py** file

```
MEDIA_URL = "/Media/"
MEDIA_PATH = "Media"
```

In your **urls.py** file

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Now create a Media folder in your root directory and then create galleryimg folder in Media folder.

Now use the following url in your template

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<img class="img-responsive" src="/Media/galleryimg/first.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you